# XPages: Scrollable DataTable - can it be done?

Tags: css, datatable, xpages

******Scrollable DataTable in XPages with Fixed Header** ****

On a DataTable , I'd like to have the view data contained within a vertical scrollable region with Header of the DataTable needs to be fixed.

Is there any way to do the same?

Please suggest.

I want to show scroll bar as per the below shown Screen Shot marked with Red Border:
[image]

Thanks and regards,

Yogesh

Comment: iNotes View control should do that.

Comment: My guess is that a data table cannot do that.  If you want that kind of functionality you will have to start using the dojo data grid or ExtJS.

Comment: Be careful what you wish for. A frequent feedback from users is, that they find the appearance of 2 scrollbars (one for the browser, one for your table) quite confusing. So you might opt for a solution where you project (using CSS and some client JS) your table header onto the HTML page.

Comment: Actually, My Project is ready. But users wants this functionality. I am generating DataTable dynamically where data coming from DB2. This dataTable work as DataGrid for me. I am doing lots of stuff by using that so @SteveZavocki I cant use other controls now. Users are Ok with appearance of 2 scroll bars (one for the browser, one for dataTable).